# Close my datepicker after losing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, focus, lostfocus

I created a datepicker in my application. When I focus on an input that has class "datepicker", my datepicker show. And when I loose focus from input, my datepicker will hide.

```
$('.datepicker').focus(function () {
    // show datepicker
}).blur(function () {
    // hide datepicker    
});
```

Anything works very well except, When I want to change month or year in datepicker, my input, looses its focus and datepicker hides.

What idea for resolve this probles?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function..

```
$('.datepicker').focusout(function(){
    //Hide
});
$('.datepicker').focusin(function(){
    //Show
});
```

May be this will help...

Answer (score 0):

you could handle the change event:

```
// when a select event occurs
$(".datepicker").focus(function() {
    // call the blur function
    $(this).blur(function() {
        // your hide function here
    });
});
```